# JQuery Mobile themeroller checkbox in List

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, checkbox, html-lists, jquery-mobile-themeroller

I'm using the theme provided by themeRoller in my personal mobile web application.

The issue I'm facing is when I use checkbox in `<li>` clause.

Probably, if we want to use themeRoller checkbox we write it like:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" />checkbox</label>
```

Above example displays the checkbox as I want but when I use the same code in `<li>` it doesn't keep the same.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Perhaps you can provide screenshots or more code. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9mmLqv3n/  Can you reproduce the problem in the fiddle?

Comment: problem is very simple brother. i use ThemeROller checkbox and it shows something like shown in here: http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/

When i use the same checkbox in list view it look like default checkbox but not this 'ThemeRoller Styled' one!

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in the fiddle I provided? Perhaps copy your theme CSS to the CSS pane...